# My Custom Vaadin 6 Theme Not Working

Tags: java, css, themes, liferay, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 6.8.13 and I've created my own theme for the sake of just styling a single button. I'm using Eclipse Luna and the Vaadin plugin, I also deploy the vaadin app as a portlet on Liferay. But my theme doesn't work...

I've done everything to the book, infact I used the vaadin theme wizard in eclipse to do everything for me. e.g. creating the

> WebContent/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css

and adding the `this.setTheme("mytheme");` in the application class. But to no avail, my styles.css file looks like this:

```
@import url(../liferay/styles.css);

.v-button-wrap {
    background: #b20000 !important; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b20000 0%, #e50000 50%, #b20000 100%) !important; /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b20000), color-stop(50%,#e50000), color-stop(100%,#b20000)) !important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b20000 0%,#e50000 50%,#b20000 100%) !important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b20000 0%,#e50000 50%,#b20000 100%) !important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b20000 0%,#e50000 50%,#b20000 100%) !important; /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b20000 0%,#e50000 50%,#b20000 100%) !important; /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b20000', endColorstr='#b20000',GradientType=0 ) !important; /* IE6-9 */
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.v-button-wrap:hover {
    border: 1px solid #990000 !important;
}
```

And my Application class looks like so:

```
import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

/**
 * Main application class.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CheckroutesportletApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Initializes the container and sets the main_screen
        Window container = new Window("Check Routes");
        container.addComponent(new MainScreen());
        setMainWindow(container);
        this.setTheme("mytheme");
    }

}
```

Anybody have an idea why this would happen? Common mistakes people make maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is, that you need to put setTheme as the very first item in the init, before vaadin lays anything out.